# Check if desktop app on Windows 8 is x86 or x64

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, task-manager

I don't see a `*32` next to file names in the Details tab of task manager like Win7 showed it. I know I am using 64-bit Windows 8. What's the easiest way to check? Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Task Manager on both 8 and 8.1 the Processes tab should show '(32 bit)' after the name of the 32 bit application.

If you prefer to use the 'Details' tab, right click in the header row and choose 'Select columns' then tick 'Platform' towards the end of the list. You now have a new column showing 32 or 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ProcessHacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), which is the best Taskmanager replacement.

Here you can add a column "Bits" to see if the process is 32 or 64Bit.

[image]